# How to sort date with tablesorter jQuery plugin in format dd mmm yy h:mm?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm using the tablesorter plugin of jQuery.
I'm trying to sort a table which has column like `04 Aug 16 18:17`.
I tried:

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter({dateFormat: "dd mmm yy h:mm"});
```

and

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter({dateFormat: "uk"});
```

and

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter({dateFormat: "pt"});
```

and

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter({dateFormat: "ddmmyy"});
```

But nothing works, can someone help me?

Comment: I think it is comparing them as strings, you can write a custom parser to convert that string to ticks and sort by the ticks. similar to this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247202/jquery-tablesorter-custom-date-format?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats going wrong is that your using a date as a datetime. DateFormat suggests its for dates.

A date has the following proppertys

- day
- month
- year

You dont have an hour and minute in a date, thats called a date time.